# Embedding Files and directories in a pdf

Tags: python, perl, pdf, encode

Is there any examples of code that can embed an entire directory with files and subdirectories into a pdf? I kwow how to write data into a pdf such that I can store say base 64 encoded data into nodes in the pdf.  However, I was looking for something that would let me actually write the data as text into the visible aspect of the document.  I was thinking maybe doing a diff of the directory against and empty directory and then writing this text to the pages of the pdf.  Is there a better way?

Comment: From your question I don't understand your intention clearly. Do you just want to display the output of a `tree`-command on a PDF page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your intention, but here is one approach:

```
tree --charset ascii /home/pipitas > pipitas-tree.txt
```

This command creates a .txt file which holds an ASCII art directory tree (with all subdirectories and files) of my home directory. Then convert this to a PDF file:

```
text2pdf -o pipitas-tree.pdf -w 842 -h 595 -m 24 pipitas-tree.txt
```

`tree` is available on most OS platforms. `text2pdf` is part of the PDFlib, also available for most OS; a free version is availble at www.pdflib.com.

Comment: Thanks, that has got me started in the right direction.  I forgot about text2pdf. -Ty